# Ignoring The Exception in Array

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am Having array of elements. I run it through the loop. Suppose if it has any error it has to skip that element and continue to the next element.

Code Sample

```
foreach (Field field in fields)
{
    try
    {
        string s = item.FieldValues[field.Title].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        form1.Controls.Add(label);
        label.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    Response.Write(field.Title);
}
```

it is showing key not found exception in item.field line. I want to ignore it and passes to next field

Comment: Are you saying that the string s = item.... line is throwing the exception? Please clarify in the question body

Comment: Try console writing field.Title in the line above the string variable. The last one in the key not found exception should be the key that item.FieldValues does not have

Answer (score 2):

Do not use exceptions to drive your code. The [FieldValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.fieldvalues.aspx) in SharePoint is a `Dictionary<string, object>` type, so you could easily check if your field exists with `ContainsKey`

```
foreach (Field field in fields)
{
    if(item.FieldValues.ContainsKey(field.Title)
    {
        string s = item.FieldValues[field.Title].ToString();
        .......
    }
    Response.Write(field.Title);
}
```

Using exceptions, just to jump to another part of your code is really a bad practice with deadly effects on performances.

If there is a way, try to avoid predictable conditions that lead to exceptions.

[See Performance Rule References: Rule DA0007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264997.aspx)
[See Exception Handling Best Practices](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET)